# A sequences problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

The first 3 terms of an infinite geometric sequence are a, b, 1 and the first 3 terms of an arithmetic sequence are a, 1, b - 4. The sum of the infinite geometric sequence is 27/4
and the sum of the first 3 terms of the arithmetic sequence is 3. Find all possible pairs of values of a and b.

I think I've gotten two pairs(correct me if I'm wrong)
a=4, b=2
a=9, b=-3

However I didn't involve either sum formulas, making me think I did something wrong, or that there are more pairs.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you find your examples? Did you check they are both correct?

Comment: The geometric sequence conditions give two pairs of answers, one of which you have found while the other looks as if you have an error.  One of these two pairs satisfies the arithmetic sequence condition while the other does not.

Comment: Please see our [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) and [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in it.

Comment: Membes of this community like to _help_ others but not to do _someone else's work_. If you show your solution and share your thoughts they will probably point out what you did good and what you did wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

You were going in the right direction, but you stopped before the finish.

Given that $a, b, 1$ make a geometric sequence, you know $a/b = b/1,$ hence $a=b^2.$

Given that $a, 1, b-4$ make an arithmetic sequence, you know $1-a = (b-4)-1,$ hence $a+b-6=0.$ This is equivalent to $b^2+b-6 = 0,$ which resolves as $b=-3$ or $b=2.$
That makes $a=b^2=9$ or $a=4,$ respectively.

You can easily check, that both resulting arithmetic sequences: $(9,1,-7)$ and $(4,1,-2)$ give a sum of the three terms equal $3.$

Now the last step, missing in your attempt: checking the sum of an infinite geometric sequence.

The sum exists, if the quotient is small enough: $|q|<1.$ This is satisfied in both cases: the quotient is $1/b,$ which is $-1/3$ in the sequence $(9,-3,1,\dots)$ or $1/2$ in the sequence $(4,2,1,\dots).$

The sum is $\frac{\text{the first term}}{1-\text{quotient}},$ which results in $\frac9{1-(-1/3)}=\frac9{4/3}=\frac{27}4$ or in $\frac4{1-1/2}=\frac4{1/2}=8.$

The latter gets discarded and we get a result: $a=9, b=-3.$